# How to hide formio loader which is by default showing when a page is loaded

Tags: angular5, formio

I have many webpages which is built on top of formio and a by default spinner is shown by default.How to hide that.
Tried couple of  css as mentioned below:

> .formio-loader-wrapper[_ngcontent-c9] {visibiilty :hidden !important}
>
> .formio-loader[_ngcontent-c9] {visibiilty :hidden !important}

both were not useful

Comment: i used .loader{
  display: none !important;
} which worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used .loader
    { display: none !important; } 
which worked for me